# Telekinetics: When buffs are up, why use Disturbance over Telekinetic Throw?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I just hit 50 on my Sage and am trying to improve my Telekinetics DPS rotation.  The guides I've found all say only to use [Telekinetic Throw](http://www.torhead.com/ability/hvB6RtQ/telekinetic-throw) when you get the [Psychic Projection](http://www.torhead.com/ability/9JBzIys/psychic-projection) proc from [Weaken Mind](http://www.torhead.com/ability/9dq2SnV/weaken-mind).  But just from looking at the abilities, my TT does ~2800 damage over 3 seconds without a crit whereas [Disturbance](http://www.torhead.com/ability/1SjTRts/disturbance) does ~1100 every GCD (1.5 seconds).  So the DPS of TT is higher by about 200.  If my buffs from Disturbance are up and I don't need to refresh them yet, why wouldn't I use TT over spamming Disturbance again?

Comment: (Disclaimer - never played swtor) I'm not sure if resources are an issue, but it doesn't seem worth spamming a DoT vs a direct damage ability.  Also I don't know the mechanics, but I would assume recasting a DoT would reset the tick timer, so you could potentially interrupt the DoT tick and lose dps this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end it seems this is due to the [Tidal Force](http://www.torhead.com/ability/6boGDuC/tidal-force) skill: Disturbance has a 30% chance to make [Telekinetic Wave](http://www.torhead.com/ability/2vXVl1u/telekinetic-wave) an instant cast, so the more you spam Disturbance the more you can use TW.  Coupled with the [Telekinetic Momentum](http://www.torhead.com/ability/aHywvuR/telekinetic-momentum) skill (and, to a much lesser degree, [Tremors](http://www.torhead.com/ability/cZiHVtd/tremors)) your DPS will definitely be higher if you save Telekinetic Throw for when Psychic Projection procs and use Disturbance as your filler move.

However, this works out to about a 2.5% increase in parses I've done; it's not the end of the world if you hit TT while PP is down.